# What would you label 'Delete oldest and Save' action?

Tags: gui-design, copywriting, labels

The (iPad) app has a limit to the number of sessions which can be saved. 
Once the limit is reached, when the user tries to save a new session he gets a dialog box telling:

> You can either delete the oldest session and make room for the new session or, you can manually go to the saved sessions page and delete the unused sessions.

**How should I label the two options?**

- 'Delete oldest and save current'
- 'Goto saved sessions page and delete manually'

The third option of cancel was a stroke of genius on my part!

The entire thing will be in a modal overlay. So there is a slight restriction of size too.

Comment: Could you not show a list to select which session(s) shall be deleted, and deactivate the Save until some session has been deleted?

Comment: Is "session" even a word that's going to make sense to your users?

Comment: @3nafish yes, session is baked into the system terminology.

Comment: @Lothar_K it is a valid option, but the app is already developed and I am just doing some tweaks for new features aka. developers don't want too much work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are effectively doing is **replacing** the oldest entry with the current one, so I would label it accordingly as:

> Replace oldest session with current session

OR

> Save current session over oldest session

In both situations, you may be able to leave 'session' out of both if it's clear to your users, but I would want to test this first.

---

For the second option, I would **focus on what the task is** not where they have to go to do it.  So something more like:

> Choose the session you want to replace with the current session

OR

> Choose sessions to delete.

I'm giving this with proper English grammar, but you could simplify it if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd not include the second option. The action is to save the session. What happens if you take the user to session management to delete sessions manually? Does their session still gets saved or not? No matter what the answer is, you don't want to confuse your users with that.

The other two options are clear: either cancel (don't save, don't quit) or delete the oldest session and then save. If the user doesn't want to overwrite the oldest session, they can use cancel and go to the session management page themselves, right?

Even better might be to simply remove the limit in the first place.